# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'generate_ticket'

Tags: android, python, kivy

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. I'm fairly new to kivy and the error might be obvious to those more experience with kivy so please impart your knowledge on to me. I'm assuming that I'm not using the function call properly in the kv language or that I didn't define the functions in the right place. If that is the case can anyone give a few pointers how to go about doing that properly.

BTW I know that some of the libraries don't have recipes for python-for-android as of the moment, I'll get to that later. I also know that I'll have to find a workaround for matplotlib/use some other method for graphing once I'm ready to port to my device.

here's my code for main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.graphics import BorderImage
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle, Line


import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
#import pylab as pl
import requests
import openpyxl as xl
#from operator import itemgetter
from collections import Counter
from lxml import html
import numpy as np

class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class LotterySelcetionScreen(Screen):
    pass

class TableScreen(Screen):
    pass

class TutorialApp(App):

    screen_manager = None

    def build(self):
        #Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)
        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(HomeScreen(name='home'))
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(LotterySelcetionScreen(name='lottery_selection'))
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(TableScreen(name='table'))

        #function to load the table form the excel file corresponding to the passed sheet name
        def loadTable(self, sheetName):
            lotteryData = pd.ExcelFile("Lottery databases.xlsx") #grabs and loads the file into memory
            df = lotteryData.parse(sheetName) #loads the data table form the corresponding sheetName into the df data frame
            return df

        #function to display the table
        def showTable(self, table):
            #get the number of rows the table has
            no_of_rows = len(table.index)
            #display the table

            return table.head(no_of_rows)

        #function to display pie charts of a specific column within the database
        #table is the database that the function will be working with
        #and column is a numberical vaule of which column to get the data from
        def printPieChart(self, table, column):
            if column == 6:
                columnList = table.iloc[:, -1:].values.T.ravel()
            else:
                columnList = table.iloc[:, (column - 7): (column - 6)].values.T.ravel()
            countedList = Counter(columnList)

            #set up the size of the pie chart
            fig = plt.figure(figsize=[10, 10])
            ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
            cmap = plt.prism()

            #input variables for pie function
            slices = [float(v) for v in countedList.values()]
            colors = cmap(np.linspace(0., 1., len(slices)))
            labels = [float(k) for k in countedList]
            columnHeaders = list(table.columns.values)

            #the pie chart
            pie_wedge_collection = ax.pie(slices, colors = colors, labels = labels, labeldistance = 1.05, autopct = '%1.1f%%')
            #get rid of the black outlines between the wedges and around the pie
            for pie_wedge in pie_wedge_collection[0]:
                pie_wedge.set_edgecolor('white')
            ax.set_title(columnHeaders[column + 1])
            #can't display a Legends as there's too many for plt.legends() too handle
            #return pyplot.pie([float(v) for v in countedList.values()], labels = [float(k) for k in countedList])

        def updateDatabase(self):
            wb = xl.load_workbook("Lottery databases.xlsx") #load the workbook into memory

            #list of the sheet names within the workbook
            sheetnames = ["SuperLotto", "MegaMillions", "Powerball"]
            days = ["Tue. ", "Wed. ", "Fri. ", "Sat. "] #days the draws on done on
            #list of the webpages to use grab the new draws
            webPages = ['http://www.calottery.com/play/draw-games/superlotto-plus/winning-numbers', 'http://www.calottery.com/play/draw-games/mega-millions/winning-numbers', 'http://www.calottery.com/play/draw-games/powerball/winning-numbers']
            x = 3
            while x != 0:
                ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheetnames[x-1]) # which sheet to update
                rowIndex = ws.get_highest_row() # gets the highest row index in the sheet
                lastCellValue = ws.cell(row = rowIndex - 1, column = 0).value #gets the last value in the first column, draw number
                page = requests.get(webPages[x-1]) #grabs the webpage needed
                tree = html.fromstring(page.text) #puts the webpage into a tree structure to make it easy to traverse
                #get the newest draw and date from the webpage for comparasion purposes
                draw_and_date = tree.xpath('//*[@id="objBody_content_0_pagecontent_0_objPastWinningNumbers_rptPast_ctl01_lblDrawDateNumber"]/text()')
                #if the table is up to date, it will move on to the next table else it will update it 
                y = int(draw_and_date[0][-4:]) - int(lastCellValue) # checks to see how many draws are missing from the table
                if y == 0:
                    #print("The table for " + sheetnames[x-1] + " is up to date.")
                    x -= 1 #decrement x by 1 to move on to the next table
                else:
                    #while loop to check if the table needs to be updated or not, if yes it will update it
                    while y != 0:
                        #grabs the draw and date of the missing draws from the table
                        draw_and_date = tree.xpath('//*[@id="objBody_content_0_pagecontent_0_objPastWinningNumbers_rptPast_ctl0' + str(y) + '_lblDrawDateNumber"]/text()')
                        numbers = tree.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/div[3]/table/tr[" + str(y) + "]/td[2]/span/text()") #numbers
                        numbers = [int(x) for x in numbers] # converts the text to integers
                        numbers.sort() #sort the number from smallest to largest
                        mega = tree.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/div[3]/table/tr[" + str(y) + "]/td[3]/text()") #mega number
                        mega = int(mega[0]) # converts the text to integers
                        #write to the file
                        if sheetnames[x-1] == "MegaMillions":
                            d = 0
                        else:
                            d = 1
                        if int(draw_and_date[0][-4:]) % 2 == 0:
                            # if the draw date is even then the day is a Friday/Saturday
                            ws.append([int(draw_and_date[0][-4:]), (days[d+2] + draw_and_date[0][:12]), numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2], numbers[3], numbers[4], mega]) # print the draw date
                        else:
                            # if the draw date is odd then the day is a Tuesday/Wednesday
                            ws.append([int(draw_and_date[0][-4:]), (days[d] + draw_and_date[0][:12]), numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2], numbers[3], numbers[4], mega])
                        y -= 1 #decrement y by 1 to get the next missing draw
                    #print("Updated the " + sheetnames[x-1] + " table successfully!")
                    x -= 1 #decrement x by 1 to move on to the next table
            wb.save("Lottery databases.xlsx") #save the workbook
            #print("Saved the database Sucessfully!")

        # function to get a list of the occurring numbers in each column
        # 6 for the first number columns or 1 for the mega/powerball column
        def getPopularList(self, table, x):
            popular_list = list()
            if x != 1:
                while x != 0:
                    column_list = table.iloc[:, (0 - x): (1 - x)].values.T.ravel() # the all of the values in the column
                    counted_list = Counter(column_list) # counts how many time each value occurs within the column
                    top_five = counted_list.most_common(5) # the top five within the column
                    top_five.sort() # sorts the top five
                    popular_list = popular_list + top_five
                    x -= 1 # decrement x by 1
            else:
                column_list = table.iloc[:, (0 - x):].values.T.ravel() # the all of the values in the column
                counted_list = Counter(column_list) # counts how many time each value occurs within the column
                top_ten = counted_list.most_common(10) # the top five within the column
                top_ten.sort() # sorts the top five
                popular_list = popular_list + top_ten
            #popular_list is actually a tuple of list which contains the value and how many times that value occured
            #but we only want the values by themselves
            popular_list_values = [y[0] for y in popular_list] #this gives us a list of the values
            return popular_list_values

        # Function to generate a ticket based on the popular numbers in the lottery
        def generate_ticket(self, table):
            firstFive = self.getPopularList(table, 6) # get the popular numbers for the first five slots
            mega = self.getPopularList(table, 1) # gets the popular numbers for the mega/powerball slot
            five = self.getNumbers(firstFive, 5) # gets first five numbers for the ticket
            one = self.getNumbers(mega, 1) #gets the mega/powerball for the ticket
            five.append(one)
            return five

        #function to get numbers
        def getNumbers(self, numbers_list, x):
            numbers = list() #empty list
            rand_range_list = list(range(0, len(numbers_list))) #list of the numbers to choice from at random
            if x != 1:
                while x != 0:
                    y = random.choice(rand_range_list) #pick a number
                    #it's not making the list properly at the moment, FIX IT!
                    #numbers = numbers + numbers_list[y] #add a number to our list to return
                    numbers.append(numbers_list[y]) #append the number to the end of the list
                    rand_range_list.remove(y) #remove y from our rand_range_list to prevent any repeats
                    x -= 1
            else:
                numbers = random.choice(numbers_list) # add a number to our list to return
            return numbers

        # function to print the ticket based on which lottery it's from
        def printTicket(self, ticket, lottery):
            #small bubblesort for the first five numbers
            for x in range(1, 5):
                for y in range(0, 4):
                    if ticket[y] > ticket[y + 1]:
                        temp = ticket[y]
                        ticket[y] = ticket[y + 1]
                        ticket[y + 1] = temp
            #print statements depending on the lottery
            #print the ticket without any brackets
            if lottery != "Powerball":
                return str(ticket)[1:-4] + " Mega " + str(ticket[-1])
            else:
                return str(ticket)[1:-4] + " Powerball " + str(ticket[-1])

        return self.screen_manager 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TutorialApp().run()
```

My tutorial.kv:

```
<HomeScreen>:
    RelativeLayout:
        Image:
            source: 'images/background3.jpg'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: self.texture_size
            pos: self.pos
        Button:
            font_size: sp(30)
            text: 'Select Lottery'
            size_hint_x: None
            width: self.texture_size[0]
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            pos: root.width / 2 - (self.width / 2), root.height / 2
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'lottery_selection'
        Button:
            size_hint_x: None
            width: self.texture_size[0]
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            pos: root.width - self.width, 0
            font_size: sp(30)
            text: 'Quit'
            on_press: app.stop()

<LotterySelcetionScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text: 'SuperLotto'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'table'
        Button:
            text: 'MegaMillions'
        Button:
            text: 'Powerball'
        Button:
            text: 'Back to home'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'home'

<TableScreen>:
    RelativeLayout:
        Label:
            id: label1
            text: str(app.root.generate_ticket(app.root.loadTable('SuperLotto')))
            height: 150
```

here's the Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/havik/workspace/kivyapp2.7/main.py", line 384, in <module>
     TutorialApp().run()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 798, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "/home/havik/workspace/kivyapp2.7/main.py", line 207, in build
     self.screen_manager.add_widget(TableScreen(name='table'))
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/uix/relativelayout.py", line 255, in __init__
     super(RelativeLayout, self).__init__(**kw)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/uix/floatlayout.py", line 66, in __init__
     super(FloatLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/uix/layout.py", line 66, in __init__
     super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 271, in __init__
     Builder.apply(self)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1872, in apply
     self._apply_rule(widget, rule, rule)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 2018, in _apply_rule
     e), cause=tb)
 kivy.lang.BuilderException: Parser: File "/home/havik/workspace/kivyapp2.7/tutorial.kv", line 45:
 ...
      43:       Label:
      44:           id: label1
 >>   45:           text: str(app.root.generate_ticket(app.root.loadTable('SuperLotto')))
      46:           height: 150
 ...
 BuilderException: Parser: File "/home/havik/workspace/kivyapp2.7/tutorial.kv", line 45:
 ...
      43:       Label:
      44:           id: label1
 >>   45:           text: str(app.root.generate_ticket(app.root.loadTable('SuperLotto')))
      46:           height: 150
 ...
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'generate_ticket'
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1649, in create_handler
     return eval(value, idmap)
   File "/home/havik/workspace/kivyapp2.7/tutorial.kv", line 45, in <module>
     text: str(app.root.generate_ticket(app.root.loadTable('SuperLotto')))

   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 2011, in _apply_rule
     value, rule, rctx['ids'])
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1654, in create_handler
     cause=tb)
```

Comment: Is your indentation correct? All your methods are indented too far, and are part of the `build()` method, not the `TutorialApp` class.

Comment: I get the same error even if I move the methods out of the build() and even if they are move to before the build()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried doing it that way inclement suggested but I couldn't properly define the screen in the build method, so I tried to fiddle with the code in kv language and was able to fix the problem. I feel really stupid for not realizing sooner. I just needed to remove root from str(app.root.generate_ticket(app.root.loadTable('SuperLotto'))) and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You instantiate a TableScreen in the build method, before `app.root` has been set, so app.root.generate_ticket doesn't exist.

One option would be to set the TableScreen content directly in the build method rather than with a kv rule.

Comment: How do I go about instantiating the screen in the build method? Do I just return the class and define it's content in the TableScreen Class?